# Fourier Convolution Inversion

Tags: fourier-analysis, convolution, inverse-function, deconvolution

Consider a Fourier convolution

$f(x) = (g * h)(x)$,

where $g$ and $h$ are arbitrary but known functions with reasonable properties. **Is there any possibility to determine the inverse function of this relation in an analytic way** so that

$x = f^{-1}( f(x) ) = \dots ?$

holds true? If yes, how does this relation look like? If no, why is it not possible?

When looking for this subject all I find is the [deconvolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution), which describes how $h$ can be determined from knowledge about $f$ and $g$. But this is certainly not my problem at hand.